# Проблема с пунктуацией при переводе с английского на русский

Tags: пунктуация, переводы

При переводе с английского часто сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией: в оригинале стоит запятая, а в переводе я не нахожу для нее никаких оснований с точки зрения правил русского языка. Хотя интонационно пауза слышится.
Например: "После нападения, группа наших людей устроила демонстрацию". В оригинале на соответствующем месте запятая стоит, а в русском варианте запятой по идее не должно быть, хотя, проговаривая фразу вслух, делаю паузу в этом месте. Так как эту паузу отразить на письме? Точнее, исходя из какого правила?
Еще пример: "Мы служители закона, без нас, вокруг до сих пор царила бы ненависть". Снова в оригинале запятая после "без нас" и слышится пауза, но в русском варианте оснований для нее я не вижу.
И таких ситуаций пруд пруди. С обстоятельством времени и места там часто ставят запятую, отражая тем самым паузу и выделяя эти обстоятельства: "В пять часов, мы уже были на месте", "В Лондоне, нас встречали, как героев".
Мне утверждают, что это уточнение, но это конечно же не тот случай, ибо уточнять тут собственно нечего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, как отразить "слышащуюся" паузу на письме, то вынужден разочаровать. В большинстве случаев графических средств для этого просто нет. В редких случаях возможна т.н. интонационная запятая, как раз такую паузу передающая. Но это действительно редкий случай, обычно в очень длинной фразе, лишённой других знаков препинания.
Кстати, этот факт никак не связан ни с английским, ни вообще с переводом. Ритмика языков, как вы понимаете, разная, в английском микропаузы - одно из выразительных средств, облегчающих понимание. В русском такого нет. Да ещё уcлышать(!) паузу в писаном тексте... Это сильно.

Answer (score 1):

Английская пунктуация совершенно отличается от русской. При переводе на русский язык вы должны руководствоваться правилами русской пунктуации.